# Why does this return the empty string?

Tags: perl

I found a code fragment in production that I didn't really understand. I tried to narrow it down to a simple example:

```
%hash = {
    'a' => 'apple',
    'b' => 'banana',
    'c' => 'cherry'
};

my $v = "Hello, " . '+' foreach (keys %hash);

print "Value = \"$v\"\n";
```

When I run this, the value of $v is the empty string, which is surprising. I'm also curious why . '+' foreach( ... ) doesn't cause an error -- I don't even have an operator between '+' and foreach( ... ), how can this possibly not cause a syntax error?

Comment: `foreach` is also statement modifier (similar to more common `if` modifier, e.g. `$y = $z if defined $z;`).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should `use warnings;`

> Reference found where even-sized list expected at test.pl line 3.

You're assigning a single value (a hashref) to `%hash` instead of a list of key/value pairs.

You should also `use strict;`.

> Use of uninitialized value $v in concatenation (.) or string at test.pl line 12.

You've put `my $v` inside a `for` loop, so it is scoped to that loop.

This code is now free of syntax errors:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %hash = (
    'a' => 'apple',
    'b' => 'banana',
    'c' => 'cherry'
);

my $v;

$v = "Hello, " . '+' foreach (keys %hash);

print "Value = \"$v\"\n";
```

… but you are overwriting `$v` with the same string (`"Hello, " . '+'`) each time you go around the loop.

---

> how can this possibly not cause a syntax error?

Since you don't have `use strict` on, lots of horrible things are allowed. It is rarely useful to run without `use strict`.

> I don't even have an operator between `'+'` and `foreach( ... )`

Your code is equivalent to:

```
foreach (keys %hash) {
    my $v = "Hello, " . '+';
}
```

It wouldn't make sense to put an operator before `foreach` or after `+'`.

Comment: Ahh Perl, you sneaky thing, you. Thanks for the explanation.